# Counting conditional statements in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, lines-of-code

I want to count the occurrence of conditional statements like if, else if, for, case. Using normal eclipse search may give results which includes "if" from a comments. Is there any plugin to do this job ?

Answer (score 0):

The closest one is [the metrics plugin](http://metrics.sourceforge.net/) or [this one](http://eclipse-metrics.sourceforge.net/). But lines of code or number of conditional statements are usually pretty bad indicators.

You should look at some of the many static code analyzers that will help you get better quality and give some actual valuable information. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730433/recommended-eclipse-plugins-for-java-source-code-analysis)